# Phoenix Framework: What's the correct way to seed database for testing?

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am building my first Phoenix app and am trying to write a test that will verify that the user retrieved from a JWT in a connection's Authentication header is the correct user, is authenticated, etc.

What is the correct way to seed the database with a single record for this test?

Should it be done:

- globally, using the `test/test_helper.exs` file, by requiring `priv/repo/seeds.exs` and executing manual Ecto operations

*OR*

- per test (in which case I am not certain how best to proceed)

**Finally**, what is the correct way to clean out the test database after successfully running my tests, so I can avoid trying to create the same record every time I run a test?

Comment: This should help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36747553/2742759

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the best way is to keep your tests separated from each other and init everything per test. Tests are run inside Ecto transactions so everything is rolled back at the end and there is no junk left. This also allows running tests in parallel. But it means the user has to be inserted at the beginning of every test manually. If you have more tests that depend on the user and current session you can extract this common code to a tag.

Usually data about logged in user is kept in `conn.assigns`. Lets pretend that it is under key `:user`.

Inside your `App.ConnCase` `setup` function add something like this:

```
setup %{conn: conn} = config do
  my_user_email = config[:logged_as]
  cond do
    my_user_email ->
      {:ok, user} = Repo.insert(...)
      conn_with_user = assign(conn, :user, user)
      {:ok, conn: conn_with_user, user: user}
  end
```

and now in your tests you can match on both conn and new account:

```
@logged_as "user.userowski@company.com"
test "JWT works correctly", %{conn: conn, user: user} do
  # user is now in the db
  # you don't have to retrieve it, because it is passed with test setup
  # you can start testing JWT 
end
```

This method is described in [Programming Phoenix](https://pragprog.com/book/phoenix/programming-phoenix). I really recommend that book!

Comment: thank you, makes a lot of sense that each test should be isolated. Will check out that book!